# Gaze tracking with the pupil-glint response how does the geometry work?

Tags: optics, geometry, geometric-optics, vision

[image]

I am struggling to understand the geometry behind the pupil glint response (see above) (With only one light source). I understand that you use the glint to find the corneal centre (Centre of corneal curvature).

Does the one light source glint pupil response require that the distance between the cornea to the camera nodal point be known? I ask because if the distance was unknown there could be several positions of the cornea that would cause the same reflection but they would all have different corneal centres, see diagram below.

[image]

Hence if you were wanted to find the normal at the point of reflection (Which helps you find the center of corneal curvature) there could be many values.

Now lets assume that I have found the normal at the point of reflection. How do i find the gaze just from the line that runs through normal at the point of reflection and the line that runs from the nodal point of the camera to the centre of the pupil?

Comment: What paper or similar is the first image from?

Comment: "General Theory of Remote Gaze Estimation Using the Pupil Center and Corneal Reflections" It mentions in the paper that it requires the head is stationary or the head position is estimated, I think this may mean that the distance to the cornea is known. [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=10CDA58407A779C1!45834&authkey=!ACb8H1VszYZ5SUA&ithint=file%2cpdf)

Comment: Yeah I think so, looks like you need two or more light sources with known positions wrt to the camera if you don't know the head position.